# How can I check to see if an SSH server is listening on a host without actually attempting a login

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to make a bash script which checks to see if a host exists and then attempts to ssh into it if an SSH server is listening on the host. The command would default to telnet if an SSH server is not listening.

What would be the best way to do this? I was thinking about using something like ssh-keyscan to just grab the public key from the ssh server, but ssh-keyscan is not on this jumpserver. Nmap is not on this server either. I'm not able to copy those binaries onto the jump server, nor am I able to compile/build anything on the jumpserver.

What would be the best way to go about checking for an SSH server? I think expect might work, though I would like to avoid using that if possible.

Comment: OK... so what _can_ you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a shell script and use `telnet` command to find remote port status

```
[root@box ~]# telnet remote.example.com 22
Trying 192.168.100.1...
Connected to remote.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
```

Sample script:

```
TELNET=`echo "quit" | telnet $SERVER $PORT | grep "Escape character is"`
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT failed"
  exit 1
else
  echo "Connection to $SERVER on port $PORT succeeded"
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: `telnet` is actually a fairly heavy protocol (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet). `nc` might be saner, if one is going to use external commands.

Comment: agreed with your solution

Comment: This one has value too -- not everyone has a copy of bash with the `/dev/tcp` extension.

Comment: ...though you could simplify it rather a lot. `if ! telnet "$server" "$port" </dev/null; then ...` will work just the same for OpenSSH; unless the "quit" were proceeded by an escape character, it's being sent to the remote server rather than being out-of-band local control, so you're depending on the remote server to close the connection when it's run with any variant of this; might as well make it short.

Comment: (btw, lower-case names are very much preferable for shell variables where possible -- I can link to portions of the POSIX standard speaking to environment variable naming convention if you're interested; that's relevant for shell variable names, as the automatic import and export implemented means that environment variables and shell variables' namespaces overlap).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  "lower-case names are very much preferable for shell variables where possible -- I can link to portions of the POSIX standard speaking to environment variable naming convention if you're interested"  I'm interested! Could you provide a link, or direct me to the best place for that kind of information?

Comment: @sndsnd, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html -- "applications shall tolerate the presence of such names", where "such names" are all-uppercase w/ digits and `_`s. Thus, an application which behaves in an undesired way because of an all-uppercase variable passed into it via the environment is buggy. Similarly: "The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you. I remember seeing (almost verbatim) "upper-case names are very much preferable for shell variables where possible" before, so this is useful.

Comment: @sndsnd, ...yar, there's a lot of cargo-cult programming in shell. Folks see upper-case names used in scripts (where accessing or working with system-impacting environment variables or shell builtins, both of which are in the reserved classes above), and assume that that's the right thing, or at least convention; and other folks see their code and copy it, ad finitum. *sigh*. (And there's outright bad/wrong references with lots of Google juice, a la TLDP)...

Answer (score 3):

Just check your ability to connect to it, if your bash has the necessary (`/dev/tcp`) extension; this requires no external commands whatsoever:

```
if (exec 2>/dev/null 4>/dev/tcp/"$hostname"/22); then
  echo "port is open"
else
  echo "unable to connect"
fi
```

Note that your script will need to start with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`, for this to work.

Comment: thanks! To be honest I preferred your version over the telnet one as it seemed cleaner, but unfortunately I did not have access to /dev/tcp

Answer (score 0):

I love oneliners :)

```
if nc "server" "port" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1;then echo yeah;else echo no;fi
```

works on my router and on my rpi